# Is it superfluous to use 'that' with Verb 'BET'?

Tags: grammar

For example 
1.She bet that her father will call her today.
2.She bet her father will call her today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not superfluous. "Bet" can be a transitive verb and can take an object for the person with whom the bet is being made: "I'll bet **you** I can run faster." Adding "that" explicitly introduces the following words as a clause, eliminating any chance the listener might hear "her father" as the object, as in:

> She bet her father **he** will call her today.

This of course goes further than your intended meaning, as your version does not specify with whom the bet is being made.